# If a ship gave a mayday/SOS call out to a coast guard and sent the lat/lng coordinates where they needed to be rescued, is WGS84 implied or assumed?

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84

Lat/Lng coordinates don't necessarily mean anything without knowing if it's WGS84 vs. something else. If a ship/crew/captain were to send an SOS call out with just coordinates, do they have to say WGS84?

Comment: Most possible ways for the captain to know where they are would be based on WGS84 (not that would matter if the ship were on fire or such), though this isn't really a GIS-centric question (and might be better suited to [outdoors.se]).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is implied and assumed, partly because WGS84 is the [standard for GPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System). It also doesn't matter, because the if the datum were confused (eg to NAD83), the deviation is small compared to the accuracy of the GPSes.